# Parsing while loop output in shell script

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I am trying to write a shell script for uninstalling android apps from my mobile phone. I want the output to be more human readable, if possible. I'll include the desired output of what I'm looking for at the bottom.

debloat.sh

```
#!/bin/sh
start=$(date +%s.%N)
packages=$(cat packages.txt)
count=0

printf "*** uninstalling packages defined in packages.txt ***\nPlease wait"

for app in $packages; do
  adb uninstall --user 0 "$packages"
  count=$((count+1))
done

duration=$(echo "$(date +%s.%N) - $start" | bc)
execution_time=`printf "%.2f seconds" $duration`

printf "Script Execution Time: $execution_time\n"
printf "Uninstalled $removed out of $count packages\n"
```

example packages.txt

```
com.google.android.webview \
com.samsung.android.lool \
com.google.android.apps.turbo \
com.google.android.apps.tachyon \
com.google.android.tts
```

Current Output

```
user@host: ./debloat.sh
*** uninstalling packages, please wait ***
Success
Failure [not installed for 0]
Failure [not installed for 0]
Failure [not installed for 0]
Failure [not installed for 0]
Script Execution Time: 6.93 seconds
Uninstalled  out of 5 packages
user@host:
```

Desired output

```
user@host: ./debloat.sh
*** uninstalling packages, please wait ***
Script Execution Time 4.26 seconds
Uninstalled 1 out of 5 packages
user@host:
```

How do I take all the output from the loop, count `Success` and display that in the `$removed` variable in the last line in `debloat.sh` ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: In your `for` loop, you are attempting to uninstall `$packages`, instead of `$app`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will not count `Success`. This will use exit status to increase the variable or not:

```
removed=0
…
for app …
  adb uninstall --user 0 "$app" >/dev/null 2>&1 && removed="$((removed+1))"
  …
done
…
```

In `foo && bar` the latter command (`bar`) will run only if the former (`foo`) returns exit status `0` (i.e. success). In your case it's like `adb … && removed=…`. The whole approach is based on the premise that `adb` returns exit status `0` for success and something else for failure, like any sane command should.

Redirections (`>`) are to make `adb` silent. Consider appending (`>>`) to a log file.

Note I'm uninstalling **one app at a time**. I *guess* your original command

> ```
> adb uninstall --user 0 "$packages"
> ```

processed them all in the first loop. This is probably the reason the four consecutive loops failed.